# How to map a list by chunks in kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I often end up with data sources like (pseudo code below, not any specific syntax, it is just to illustrate):

```
list = {
  "XLabel", 
  "XDescription", 
  "YLabel", 
  "YDescription", 
  "ZLabel", 
  "ZDescription"
}
```

desired output is:

```
list = { 
  MyClass("XLabel", "XDescription"), 
  MyClass("YLabel", "YDescription"), 
  MyClass("ZLabel", "ZDescription")
}
```

Is there anything more clean than to do a `fold()`, and fold it into a new list? I've also rejected doing something weird like `list.partition().zip()`

I basically want a more powerfull `map` that would work like `mapChunks( it1, it2 -> MyClass(it1, it2))` where the chunking is part of the function so it gets easy and nice. (My example has the list in chunks of two, but 3 is also a prevalent use case.)

Does this function exist? Or what is the most idiomatic way to do this?

Comment: "I've also rejected doing something weird like list.partition().zip() or" - this sentence is incomplete, isn't it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the `chunked` function, and then `map` over the result. The syntax gets very close to what you wanted if you destructure the lambda-argument:

```
list.chunked(2)
    .map { (it1, it2) -> MyClass(it1, it2) }
    // Or use _it_ directly: .map { MyClass(it[0], it[1]) }
```

Answer (score 5):

I think the `windowed` method should do what you want.

```
lst.windowed(size = 2, step = 2, partialWindows = false) { innerList -> MyClass(innerList[0], innerList[1]) }
```

You can also use `chunked` but it calls `windowed` under the hood. But with chunked you can get lists that have fewer elements than you were expecting

EDIT to answer [@android developer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/878126/android-developer)'s question about getting the indexes of the list

```
val lst = listOf(7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16)
val windowedList = lst.mapIndexed { index, it -> index to it }
    .windowed(size = 2, step = 2, partialWindows = false) {
        it[0].first
    }
println(windowedList)
```

Would output

```
[0, 2, 4, 6, 8]
```

Comment: This is actually great, but I think you've forgotten the `step` parameter (for `windowed`) that should be of the same value as `size`. Also, do you know if it's possible to get the indices for each list it produces? It helps with error logs...

Comment: @androiddeveloper you're right, I did miss the `step` parameter (I guess I didn't read the question well enough initially). I don't believe the `windowed`, or `chunked`, functions pass the indices. You could, however, add a `mapIndexed` step and create a `Pair` of index to value and then execute the `windwed` function and you would have the index information

Comment: I actually found `windowed` useful. I don't understand what `chunked` does. Similar? Same? Can you please update your answer with the correct code, and show how it's done using the other solutions you've mentioned now?

Comment: @androiddeveloper `chunked` is basically the same as calling `windwoed` with the same value for `size` and `step` and `partialWindows` equal to `true`.

Comment: Oh so it's the more common case, which I used anyway. Thank you!  Can you please update the answer to include `chunked` snippet too?

Answer (score 1):

To add to the existing answers, you can use `chunked` function with the transform lambda passed as its second argument:

```
list.chunked(2) { (label, description) -> MyClass(label, description) }
```

This way is more efficient because the temporary list of two elements is reused across all chunks.

Answer (score 0):

https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/chunked.html

Chunked returns a sub list of the size you specify

This is the API call you want

considering your list is in pairs of 2 you can do this

```
list.chunked(2)  //List<List<String>>
    .map{MyClass(it[0], it[1]} //list<MyClass>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create an **extension function**, for example `mapChunks`, and reuse it:

```
fun List<String>.mapChunks(): List<MyClass> {
    return chunked(2).map { MyClass(it[0], it[1]) }
}

val list1 = listOf(
    "XLabel",
    "XDescription",
    "YLabel",
    "YDescription",
    "ZLabel",
    "ZDescription"
)
val result1 = list1.mapChunks()

val list2 = listOf(
        "XLabel1",
        "XDescription1",
        "YLabel1",
        "YDescription1",
        "ZLabel1",
        "ZDescription1"
)
val result2 = list2.mapChunks()
```